# I am using sails-swagger to generate the swagger docs i am getting only json format documnetation not swagger ui

Tags: node.js, sails.js, swagger, swagger-ui

[image]

This is the document i am getting but not the swagger ui. I want to get the document in swagger-ui format
I have used https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-swagger

Answer (score 0):

`sails-swagger` doesn't provide swagger-ui. You need to set up it by yourself and point to `/swagger/doc`.

Comment: Hi @Zuker i downloaded Swagger-ui and i am pointing to my swagger/docs but it is saying  Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings. i have set the cors header too in sailsjs but in response in am not seeing the headers whcih i have set in sails js

Comment: I think you're facing this issue: https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-swagger/issues/17